# How to solve “Error generating PK : entity not supported” when using Cayenne

Tags: apache-cayenne

When committing changes to an Apache Cayenne context, I get an exception like the following.

```
org.apache.cayenne.CayenneRuntimeException: [v.3.0.1 Sep 06 2010 15:09:38] 
Error generating PK : entity not supported: SOME_TABLE
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column that is part of the primary key of SOME_TABLE has no value. Therefore Cayenne tries to generate one, but does not know how to.

To solve the problem, do one of the following.

- If the value is supposed to be auto-generated, tell Cayenne how to generate the value.
- If it is not supposed to be generated, provide a value before committing changes in the context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a key generation strategy in Cayenne modeler. Documentation can be found in the [Cayenne reference](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc/primary-key-generation.html).

Normally Cayenne does not expose the PK to the user in the Object Entity classes. You can override that, but think very carefully before you make your PK meaningful.